# Receiving java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError on badlogic.BufferUtils

Tags: java, libgdx

When lunching the application with **DesktopLuncher** i experience `UnsatisfiedLinkError` on root class (Main) in core module inside the project.

```
public class Main extends Game {

    @Override
    public void create() {
        this.cameraBuilder = ...
        setScreen(new LandingMenu(this));
    }
    
    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
    }
    
    public World getWorld() {
        return world;
    }
    
    public SpriteBatch getBatch() {
        return batch;
    }
    
    public CameraBuilder<OrthographicCamera> getCameraBuilder() {
        return cameraBuilder;
    }
    
    private final SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();;
    
    private CameraBuilder<OrthographicCamera> cameraBuilder;
    
    private final World world = new World(new Vector2(0, -9.8f), true);
}
```

any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please consider to approve provided answers if it satisfy the requirement, otherwise feel free to eace comment.

Comment: Thanks, the issue was on initializing the sprite batch inside create method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is a cause and issue lives on `create` method on `ApplicationListener` Called when the Application is first created, on the other hand SpriteBatch is a Batch which is used for drawing Sprites, more specifically, it deals with drawing a bunch of textures on Quads in OpenGL thus is must be initialized inside of create method and not in the root class level.

```
    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        setScreen(new LandingMenu(this));
    }
    
    ...
    
    private SpriteBatch batch;
```

Find more in [here](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html).